# Currently cubic_meter columns are string. Must convert the type to double precision. (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, types, migration, double, precision

Laravel + Postgres

[Need to change the type of cubic_meter to double precision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWoQD.png)

[Error im getting when doing the migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS0Za.png)

Comment: Please, instead of posting screen shots report the code / logs in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using migrations wrong. Try something like:

```
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->double('cubic_meters')->change();
});
```

Comment: Have try these method. The eloquent API is not working

Comment: If the Eloquent API isn't working, it sounds like that should be your question.